# How to serializing access a udp::socket object in multiple threads (in boost/asio)?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, coroutine, asio

if i use strand to achieve my purpose:

method 1:

```
co_spawn(strand, []() -> awaitable<void> {
        co_await a_socket.async_receive_from(...., use_awaitable);
      }, detached);
```

or:

```
co_await co_spawn(strand, []() -> awaitable<void> {
        co_await a_socket.async_receive_from(...., use_awaitable);
      }, use_awaitable);
```

method 2:

```
co_await a_socket.async_receive_from(...., asio::bind_executor(strand, use_awaitable));
```

method 3:

```
udp::socket socket(strand); // construct
    co_await a_socket.async_receive_from(...., use_awaitable);
```

which is the right method?